# My wordpress site .htaccess gets 's' appended

Tags: wordpress

My site keeps telling me this error:

`/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 's', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

After editing the .htaccess file and remove the 's', it'll work fine.
However, after a while I'm still getting the same error.

Why the .htaccess file is edited? By whom? How to prevent that?

Comment: I understand you don't wanna share your .htaccess code, but could you please give an example of how the 's' gets appended?

Comment: try to delete it and go to permalink section, check that all thee fields are correct ( no stray `s` in fields ) and regenerate thee .htacess again

Comment: @ObmerkKronen which permalink section? I tried my wordpress one but there are just radio boxes

Comment: you mean [this one](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen)? Look down at `category base` and `tag base` , is that empty ? I should also mention that you should check this only with all plugins disabled AND thee default WP theme.  plugin or theme might trigger `.htaccess` changes with simple functions .

Comment: I have the same problem, and many more people seem to have it too. The symptom: At the end of the .htaccess file, a new line is added, containing a single "s". Sometimes it is "s", but I have also seen "ss" once. I still have not found the actual problem, though.

Comment: Also: This problem is already asked about on the Wordpress SE: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28202/htaccess-and-500-error-extra-character-added